# Find the biggest chunks of same data in a binary file

Tags: python, binaryfiles

I've a file that contains binary data. There is an error in generating the file and some data is written to the file more than once. Now I'm looking for a method to find big chunks of same datablocks in one file. I tried to figure it out with difflib. But I think its not the rigth tool for my needs.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: A suffix tree would allow you to find the longest common sequences.

Comment: Fixing the error in the file generation is not possible, or you must fix the already existing files?

Comment: The bug in the file generation is not reproducable. I try to get as much information as possible from the corrupt file.

Comment: I was looking about some information on suffix trees. But I'm not sure how to find same data in the tree. I'm thinking of using a library for generating the tree (http://www.daimi.au.dk/~mailund/suffix_tree.html, or any better suggestions?) but how can I find duplicate data in the tree? Thanks for any help!